# How to make file path from list of strings using itertools?

Tags: python, python-itertools

Is there a slick way to make this a one liner using itertools?  I didn't see it?  Thanks.

`datapath=['path','to','data']
datapathstring=''
for d in datapath:
  datapathstring+='/'+d`

Comment: `itertools` is awesome, but it's not the solution to _all_ problems. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What?

```
>>> os.path.join(*datapath)
'path/to/data'
>>> os.path.abspath(os.path.join(*(['/'] + datapath)))
'/path/to/data'
```

Comment: What does this `*` means in `*datapath`?

Comment: @Berci: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Ah, uses the elements of the list/tuple as argument list, nice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['path','to','data']
b = "/".join(a)
```

or

```
b = os.path.join(*a)
```